# Issue in using calendar component - primefaces 3.1

Tags: primefaces

I'm getting the following error on using calendar component:
**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'datepicker'**
This problem is coming in primefaces.js (PrimeFaces.widget.Calendar).

The code is:

```
<p:column id="startDate">
    <p:calendar value="#{article.startDate}" mode="inline"
        id="inlineCal" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
    </p:calendar>
</p:column>
```

What could be the possible issues ?

Thanks,
Shikha

Comment: is there another include of jquery in your project (except the one that come with primefaces)? maybe one that comes with another JSF component library like richfaces

Comment: Did you correctly include PF javascript libs? This boils down to: Do you use `h:head`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel pointed out, Jquery library was included explicitly. thereby causing conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem: "**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'datepicker'**". Looking for cure I stumbled upon this question.

But in my case it turned out to be a "simple" browser caching problem of the jquery.js when I downgraded from primefaces 3.5 to 3.4.2.

Some primefaces javascript was not compatible with the jquery.js then. I have not further investigated which (primefaces js or jquery js) was cached and which one was updated.

Clearing the cache solved it. Mabye this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In my case

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

on the onload event has helped.